# Provide a prompt answer during some script execution

Tags: bash

I have these three sh scripts which are doing some sql scripts in oracle database. After some initial updates the scrip ask a question which needs to be answered by pressing J  . But now i have to provide this answer manually whenever it stops.
Does anyone have an idea about how should i provide this answer so that all the script will be finished without my intervention??

```
./1.sh  A B  && \
./2.sh  A B  && \
./2.sh  A B
```

Comment: depends on which script asks and how it asks for input...

Comment: It just asks for an input either J or N. Just these two entries. all the scripts are requesting the same input!

Comment: do you have to press enter?

Comment: anyways, check `expect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can do this. Redirect stdin so that it takes its input from a file.

ie

```
/1.sh  A B 0<ip1.txt && \
./2.sh  A B 0<ip2.txt && \
./2.sh  A B 0<ip3.txt
```

where ip1.txt, ip2.txt, ip3.txt etc contains your reply for each of the scripts respectively. It is restricted in that only one reply can be used per script.

You could tweak this ipi.txt files to redirect script responds to stdout.